# onClick executing a function and setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck with this one function,
I have an onClick that when a user clicks on it, it has to perform two things based on the If statement, one function and one state, but it doesnt seem to work:

in my code i want the row when it is Not disabled to do “doScore” as well as “rolling : true” but I don't know how to write it that it works

```
function RuleRow({ doScore, name, score, description, rolling }) {
const disabled = score !== undefined;

  return (
<tr
  className={`RuleRow RuleRow-${disabled ? "disabled" : "active"}`}
  onClick={disabled ? null : doScore}
>
  <td className="RuleRow-name">{name}</td>
  <td className="RuleRow-score">{disabled ? score : description}</td>
</tr >
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function RuleRow({ doScore, name, score, description, rolling }) {
  const disabled = score !== undefined;

  const handleClick = () => {
      if (score !== undefined && rolling) {
          // do something
      } else {
          doScore();
      }
  };

  return (
    <tr
      className={`RuleRow RuleRow-${disabled ? "disabled" : "active"}`}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <td className="RuleRow-name">{name}</td>
      <td className="RuleRow-score">{disabled ? score : description}</td>
    </tr >
  );
}
```

Comment: mamnon! but how about rolling: true? where do i add it in handleClick?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: rolling is a state?

Comment: yes it is a state, i want it to do the score as well as rolling with one click.

Comment: You must pass setRolling as a prop and use that: `setRolling(true);`

Comment: `function RuleRow({ doScore, name, score, description, setRolling }) {`

Comment: thank you! ill try that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest solution but you could use an arrow function that has null if disabled or else a function body that calls two functions:

```
onClick={disabled ? null : (evt) => { doScore(evt); this.setState({ rolling: true }); }}
```

Recommended way to go would be to create a custom function that calls both functions or just set state `rolling: true` in the doScore function if possible.

Comment: actually i did try adding the `rolling: true` to my doScore function  but it crashed it.

Comment: If you include the declaration of the `doScore` function I might be able to help. If you're using it in a separate function outside of the React component then `this` will no longer be the React component but the context of `doScore` function (i.e. it won't know about the setState).

Comment: this is the doScore function and it is in a different component, additionally theyre functional components so idk about `this`

Comment: `function doScore(ruleName, ruleFn) {
    // evaluate this ruleFn with the dice and score this rulename
    setState((st) => ({
      ...state,
      scores: { ...st.scores, [ruleName]: ruleFn(state.dice) },
      rollsLeft: NUM_ROLL,
      locked: Array(NUM_DICE).fill(false),

    }));
    //animateRoll();
  }`

Comment: And rolling is in state of a parent function component of the `RuleRow`?

Comment: yes it is, you can see the code of these two components here
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-merkle-nco0m?file=/src/RuleRow.js

Comment: Oh, that helps, thanks!

You can create a function `setRolling(rolling) { setState({ rolling }); }` on the parent component and pass that function as a param to the `RuleRow` component. Then from the `RuleRow` you can call both doScore and setRolling as defined in my answer above: `(evt) => { doScore(); setRolling(true); }`

Comment: thank you so so much for your detailed explanation! ill do that.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Or at least try to :')

Answer (score 0):

1. specify please what is `rolling` prop (which values can be passed as `rolling`) and how it should impact on `RuleRow` component. For now I see no mention of `rolling` inside component.
2. As you can see from snippet below, your function `doScore` will run on `onClick` if `score` not strictly equal to `undefined`. So either `score` is equal `undefined`, or `doScore` is invalid function or is not function at all. So I suppose there are something with `doScore`. Provide please what you pass in this prop.
3. If you want update state of component which is parent of `RuleRow` component. You should write smth like `const [score, setScore] = useState('initial score')`. Paste `setScore` to `RuleRow` as prop. And then inside `RuleRow` write `onClick={disabled ? null : () => setScore('anything what you want')}`. `score` inside parent component will be updated and `RuleRow` will be rerendered.

```js
function App() {
  const score = undefined;
  const disabled = score !== undefined;

  console.log('value of disabled id ', disabled);

  return (
    <table className="App">
      <tr onClick={disabled ? null : () => console.log("clicked")}>Hello, click me!</tr>
    </table>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```